# Where are my domains when logging in with SFTP user?

Tags: ftp, sftp

I used to connect to my server using FTP using TLS but that was removed. So I updated my account to use SFTP. When I logged back into my account I do not see any of my domains. When I was using FTP I could see all of my domains. I see a lot more additional directories but I haven't been able to find any of my domains.

In my root directory is a folder "/home". I think that's where my domains may be but when I click on that it gives me this error:

```
SSH_FXP_OPENDIR
SSH_FXP_STATUS
Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if I attach the domain name to the path it skips the home directory and shows the domains. I have a field Path in my connections options and it's named the same as the server. So:

```
server: mydomain.com
path: /mydomain.com
```

shows my domains using SFTP correctly.